# Google Calendar API in ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working on one project with **Angular 13 and .NET Core 6**. And I need to make it possible for users to **connect Google calendars** to their account. I started by studying the documentation and created the first version of this functionality, but I ran into a big problem. Calendars were only connected locally on my laptop, and after the deployment, this option became unavailable. As it turned out, it cannot be used for web applications **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker**. How can I solve this problem? I searched everywhere but still haven't found the solution (
P.S.: Authorization and Authentication created with Firebase.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3 - the ASP.NET Core 3 library should work fine in 6.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you using Google OAuth.
So when you navigate to the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
You can observe API Keys and OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and Service Accounts.

Navigate to the your OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
And see two sections - Authorized JavaScript origins, Authorized redirect URIs

Add the URL to the your website into both sections and your problem be solved.